# Join 3 tables using column common to all 3 tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am a total SQL novice, so please bear with me. I have three tables that are set up in the following fashion:

date|country|Test 1|Test 2|Test 3|etc.

The data in the date and country columns are identical across the three tables, and the differences are in the data in the Test columns. I'd like to use Join to query one date column and the three corresponding Test columns from the three tables.
I'm planning on just re-building the table so that the Test columns in the other tables are additional columns in the one table, but I'd still like to know how to use Join in this way. This is what I have at the moment, although it's throwing an error saying that there's an error in the syntax of the FROM clause. It's worth noting that I'm running this query in VBA using an Access DB.

```
     SELECT r.CRDate, r.Test, p.Test, z.Test
     FROM CountryRaw as r
         INNER JOIN CountryPct as p ON p.CPctDate = r.CRDate
         INNER JOIN CountryZ as z ON z.CZDate = p.CPctDate
     WHERE r.Country = 'US' AND p.Country = 'US' AND z.Country = 'US'
```

I came across something using `SELECT COALESCE(r.CRDate, p.CPctDate, z.CZDate)` to start, but I didn't get anywhere with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires extra parentheses.  So try this:

```
SELECT r.CRDate, r.Test, p.Test, z.Test
FROM (CountryRaw as r INNER JOIN
      CountryPct as p
      ON p.CPctDate = r.CRDate
     ) INNER JOIN
     CountryZ as z
     ON z.CZDate = p.CPctDate
 WHERE r.Country = 'US' AND p.Country = 'US' AND z.Country = 'US'
```

Comment: Brilliant. Any recommendations of useful resources for Access-specific modifications to SQL?

Additionally, would it matter if I joined the third table on `z.CZDate = r.CRDate`, meaning that I'm joining both of the latter two tables via the first table?

Comment: @MichaelSmith . . . No.  My recommendation is always to move off of MS Access.

Comment: Ha! Good to know. I'm learning SQL in PostGreSQL. I need to find out which dbms my company uses.